Error in Web Sphere Application Server Starting
I am trying to run Web Sphere Application Server 9 locally using Rational Application Developer IDE.
I am getting the below error -
[6/6/24 13:10:54:297 IST] 0000004a SSLHandshakeE E   SSLC0008E: Unable to initialize SSL connection.  
Unauthorized access was denied or security settings have expired.
Exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

at com.ibm.jsse2.aj.i(aj.java:62)
at com.ibm.jsse2.aj.a(aj.java:82)
at com.ibm.jsse2.bg.f(bg.java:112)
at com.ibm.jsse2.bg.e(bg.java:293)
at com.ibm.jsse2.bg.unwrap(bg.java:4)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:41)
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.readyInbound(SSLConnectionLink.java:586)
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.ready(SSLConnectionLink.java:346)
at       `com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)`
 at `com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)`
 at `com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)`
 at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
 at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
 at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
 at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
 at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
 at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
 at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1909)


Looks like RAD is trying plain text connection. Make sure you have Security turned on in the server configuration in RAD

@Gas - Turned on security on this server also not working. Looks like some certificate issue

Try to start/stop the server directly, not from RAD. And see if you can access std admin console like http://localhost:9060/ibm/console. Check SystemOut.log if the server starts correctly.

@Gas -Yes this thing is working and i am able to access ibm console now. Do I need to do some settings change after logging into console ?

Check the secuirity settings and ports. They have to match with what you will set in RAD.
